# How to pass 2 different struct with the same named elements to one function?

Tags: c, function, struct

I have declared two structures with the same named elements, like this:

```
struct sParametersUdc
{

    float PI;
    float C1;
    float C2;
    float error_old;
    float imin;
    float imax;
};

struct sParametersD
{

    float PI;
    float C1;
    float C2;
    float error_old;
    float imin;
    float imax;
};

EXTERN struct sParametersPll parameterspll;
EXTERN struct sParametersUdc parametersudc;
```

And my question now is, if it is possible to create a single function, which I could use with both structures? I've tried a solution below, but it's not working, because it can't find the other structure.

```
void regulator(struct sParametersUdc *udc, float error);

void regulator(struct sParametersUdc *udc, float error)
{   

    (udc->PI)+= (udc->C1)*error + (udc->C2)*(udc->error_old);


    if(udc->PI > udc->imax)  udc->PI = udc->imax;
    if(udc->PI < udc->imin)  udc->PI = udc->imin;

    udc->error_old = error;

}

regulator(&parametersudc, error_udc);

regulator(&parametersd, error_d);
```

Comment: Off course it does not work since you expect `struct sParametersUdc` parameter and not the other even if they have same named field they are different types. What you could do I guess it to expect a void pointer and cast it based on maybe a 3rd parameter to the right type.

Comment: If they are identical, why have two structs and not use just one?

Comment: You need to explain further what you are trying to accomplish. There are multiple possible solutions for this, and the correct recommendation depends on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: In my code I have multiple PI regulators and I want to use only one function and save the values in seperate structures. 
I tried solution from @idris and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use one function with two diffrent structure. In C you must define 2 diffrent function or change your structure like this

```
struct sParameters
{
float PI;
float C1;
float C2;
float error_old;
float imin;
float imax;
};

struct sParametersD
{
    struct sParameters sp;
};

struct sParametersUdc
{
    struct sParameters sp;
};

void regulator(struct sParameters *sp, float error)
{   

    (sp->PI)+= (sp->C1)*error + (sp->C2)*(sp->error_old);

    if(sp->PI > sp->imax)  sp->PI = sp->imax;
    if(sp->PI < sp->imin)  sp->PI = sp->imin;

    sp->error_old = error;
}
```

Now you can call like this

```
regulator(&parametersudc.sp, error_udc);
regulator(&parametersd.sp, error_d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a union with the two structures in it.

```
union foo {
sParametersD D;
sParametersUdc Udc;
}
```

Then pass that to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an union of both structures. From [C11 6.5.2.3p6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p6):

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members.

Assuming both structures share a "common initial sequence", ie. have the compatible types for initial members, you can access one using another.

```
struct sParametersUdc {
    float PI;
    float C1;
    float C2;
    float error_old;
    float imin;
    float imax;
};

struct sParametersD {
    float PI;
    float C1;
    float C2;
    float error_old;
    float imin;
    float imax;
};

union sParameters {
    struct sParametersUdc udc;
    struct sParametersD d;
};

void regulator(union sParameters *param, float error)
{   
    struct sParametersUdc *udc = &param->udc;
    udc->PI += udc->C1 * error 
        + udc->C2 * udc->error_old;

    if (udc->PI > udc->imax) {
        udc->PI = udc->imax;
    }
    if (udc->PI < udc->imin)  {
        udc->PI = udc->imin;
    }

    udc->error_old = error;
}

int main() {
    struct sParametersUdc udc;
    regulator(&(union sParameters){ .udc = udc }, 1.0);
    struct sParametersD d;
    regulator(&(union sParameters){ .d = d }, 1.0);
}
```

Doing things like that can be helpful in some occasions, but I think here it only serves as a trick and lowers code quality. From what you've shown, this looks like calculating output from the integral part of PID regulator. I believe your code should just create a single structure to represent this "object" from both structures and a single function to handle it, like in @idris answer.

Comment: This rule says you can “inspect,” *i.e.* read, the structure. It does not say you can modify it.

Comment: Och. So this is wrong? So I have a question, [the second example from p9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p9) is invalid from 2 reasons - union is not visible _and_ it modifies the structure?

Comment: We cannot tell; `f` modifies `*p2` (`u.s2`) but not `*p1` (`u.s1`), but we do not know which one was the latest properly set by the code in `/* ... */`.